# Fragment view reference unsuitable for Snackbar after app close/re-open

Tags: android

My app crashes when I trigger a HTTP request that will eventually update a `LiveData` instance in the `ViewModel`, which is being observed by a Fragment. When updated, the Fragment will create a Snackbar with the `view` provided by `onViewCreated`.

When this happens, this exception is thrown:

```
2022-01-03 16:51:50.758 6395-6395/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.grecotech.lookingafterludo.android, PID: 6395
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No suitable parent found from the given view. Please provide a valid view.
        at com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar.makeInternal(Snackbar.java:198)
        at com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar.make(Snackbar.java:157)
        at com.grecotech.lookingafterludo.android.fragment.action.ActionFragment.onCreateSuccess(ActionFragment.java:59)
        at com.grecotech.lookingafterludo.android.fragment.action.ActionFragment.lambda$onCreateView$1$ActionFragment(ActionFragment.java:42)
        at com.grecotech.lookingafterludo.android.fragment.action.ActionFragment$$ExternalSyntheticLambda5.onChanged(Unknown Source:8)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:133)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:146)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$ObserverWrapper.activeStateChanged(LiveData.java:468)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$LifecycleBoundObserver.onStateChanged(LiveData.java:425)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:354)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.forwardPass(LifecycleRegistry.java:265)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:307)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.java:148)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:134)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentViewLifecycleOwner.handleLifecycleEvent(FragmentViewLifecycleOwner.java:62)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:3028)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.start(FragmentStateManager.java:589)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:300)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1647)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3126)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:3077)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchStart(FragmentController.java:262)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:510)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:210)
        at com.grecotech.lookingafterludo.android.activity.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:69)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1435)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8231)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3861)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8633)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

This is the Fragment code:

```
private ActionViewModel viewModel;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(ActionViewModel.class);
  var viewBinding = FragmentActionBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
  viewBinding.setModel(viewModel);
  return viewBinding.getRoot();
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  var lifecycleOwner = getViewLifecycleOwner();
  viewModel.onCreateSuccess().observe(lifecycleOwner, scheduleItem -> onCreateSuccess(viewModel, view, scheduleItem));
}

private void onCreateSuccess(ActionViewModel viewModel, View view, ScheduleItem scheduleItem) {
  Snackbar.make(view, getString(R.string.action_saved), 5000).show();
}
```

Seems the `view` in `onCreateSuccess` is no longer valid. I've looked into using `requireView()` but it seems it also uses the same view reference.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It's likely that your `ViewModel` outlives your `View`. Can you show where does the instance of the `viewModel` in `onViewCreated` come from? I'm seeing the line `viewModel.onCreateSuccess()...` but I can't see where does that `viewModel` live. I'm also seeing you're creating a `var viewModel =` in your `onCreateView` but never assign it to a global scoped variable.

Comment: Apologies @OnurD. I've edited the post, I am indeed assigning the view model to a field variable

Comment: I suspect that your Fragment's `View` is not attached to any context by the time you get a `onChanged` callback from your `LiveData`. What I'd suggest is just passing `requireActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content)` as your View

`Snackbar.make(requireActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content), getString(R.string.action_saved), 5000).show();`

Comment: Can you check `view.isAttachedToWindow` in `onCreateSuccess`?

`android.util.Log.d("IS_ATTACHED", Boolean.toString(view.isAttachedToWindow());`

If we see that this is the case, then we're going to need to figure out why would our LiveData observer outlive the lifecycle of our View

Comment: @OnurD. If I replace the Snackbar view with `requireActivity().findViewById(R.id.content)` then I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No suitable parent found from the given view. Please provide a valid view.`

Comment: just to confirm, did you use `R.id.content` or `android.R.id.content` ?

Comment: I used `R.id.content`, I see it works with `android.R.id.content` - apologies I am new to Android development and missed the difference

Comment: the result of `view.isAttachedToWindow` in `onCreateSuccess` is `true`

Comment: Yeah no worries. I'm glad that it is working when content view is manually found and used instead. This is not the best solution but think of it as a workaround for now. Snackbar should have done the job for finding that as a suitable parent in the first place but it won't work only when your View was "detached". That was what I suspected until you said that the boolean actually turned out as "true".. I strongly suggest that you have a look at Snackbar sourcecode, especially the method `findSuitableParent` and try to debug where does the logic fail.

Comment: i agree it seems a workaround, i would expect the callback not to be called at all or for the LiveData to have been stopped along with the view, as you say it seems the ViewModel is living longer than the view. I've no idea what I'm doing wrong. I see some people set `viewBinding.setLifecycleOwner(this);` for Fragments, not sure if that's relevant. Either way, thanks for your help!